# YouTube API: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: api, youtube

I'm using the YouTube API and I keep getting 
"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" for the second line of code here:

```
$(".addVideoUrlBtn").on("click", function(){
 player.loadVideoByUrl(mediaContentUrl: videoUrl, 
 startSeconds:0, 
 suggestedQuality:"large"):Void
})
```

The code is practically copied and pasted from YouTube api docs here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference so I'm not sure why I'm getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're taking the docs too literally. The examples shown are a) not valid js (because they aren't supposed to be) b) showing the TYPES of expected argument

when they say

```
player.cueVideoById(videoId:String,
                    startSeconds:Number,
                    suggestedQuality:String):Void
```

they mean that the function `player.cueVideoById` takes arguments `videoId`, `startSeconds`, and `suggestedQuality` which are a `String`, `Number`, and `String` respectively and that its return type is `Void` (nothing)

```
$(".addVideoUrlBtn").on("click", function(){
 player.loadVideoByUrl(url, 0, "large")
})
```

is that you want